# Android NDK Project Folder Structure C++

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Tactical question:

When I create a new NDK project in Android Studio,

I get the default folder structure:

*app/src/main/cpp/*

with native-lib.cpp.

If I right-click on app, I get option to create JNI folder:

*apps/src/main/jni/*

Where should I put my native code?

I currently have projects where

*/app/src/main/cpp/[lib_name]/* with *.h and *.cpp.

Should I move them to **jni** folder?

What is the standard going forward?

The fact that the app is creating these 2 folders may mean that the intent is to create the interface in the JNI folder and the libraries kept separate in cpp/libXFolder/. Is this the right interpretation? But then why is the native-lib.cpp interface file put in the cpp folder?

Any help appreciated :)